Is there a way to set Tax Item field on customer record from REST web service?
I am new to fairly NetSuite and trying to create a customer record with taxitem default to "non-taxable" (one of the values) but have been unsuccessful. The idea is to be able to create sales orders non-taxable.
Can someone suggest if this field is exposed to REST API?
I have tried setting taxable field to false but the field is not exposed to the Rest API.
I am open to alternative method as well.

-8 seems like an odd number to make something non-taxable?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
